# qrand is returning always 0

Tags: c++, qt

I need to get random numbers between 0 and 1.
As 0.54321, 0.8912, 0.1234342, 0.0000123 and etc

I put this code in my main and also Application constructor:

```
       qsrand(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toTime_t());
```

And used this code inside one of my slots:

```
       float prob = qrand() % 1;
```

I tried int, double as a return value, but it is always returning 0.

Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`qrand()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qrand)  generates integer numbers between `0` to `RAND_MAX` and every number is perfectly divisible by `1` and giving remainder as `0`.  Try this instead:

```
 float prob = (float) qrand() / (RAND_MAX+1); // 1 is exclusive
```

Comment: Ok. Maybe I misunderstood something. And how should I then get random numbers between 0 and 1?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ; How `%2` would help in generating number between `0` to `1`.?

Comment: @haccks Ooop's sorry, you're right of ourse. I thought producing a series of `0`s and `1`s.

Comment: The code of yours is giving me this error:                                     invalid operands of types "float" and "int" to binary "operator%". When I delete the float on the right side it gives me huge numbers like 2345.

Comment: invalid operands of types "float" and "int" to binary "operator%"

Comment: @user3185491; OK. I should think about that before. Change `%` to `/`.